# How to prove the existence of maximum and minimum of this set?

Tags: continuity, maxima-minima, differential

In Analysis I by Herbert Amann, Chap IV, Sec 2, Remarks 2.2 (b), there is a proposition as follows:

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b](\subseteq\mathbb{R})$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Then
> $$\max_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)=f(a)\vee f(b)\vee \max\{f(x);x\in(a,b),f'(x)=0\}$$
> that is, $f$ attains its maximum either at an end point of $[a,b]$ or at a critical point in $(a,b)$. Similarly
> $$\min_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)=f(a)\wedge f(b)\wedge \min\{f(x);x\in(a,b),f'(x)=0\}$$

Now for simplicity, let $E:=\{f(x);x\in(a,b),f'(x)=0\}$. Of course, because of the compactness of $[a,b]$ and the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$,  $\sup E$ and $\inf E$ are well defined, but how could I know the set $E$ has well defined maximum and minimum? What if the set $E$ has actually infinite number of elements?

For example, let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}(for\ x\neq 0, f(0)=0)$. Clearly $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, but has infinite critical points.
(This is just a specific example to explain why I consider this problem, I'm trying to figure out whether the existence of maximum and minimum is true for a general function that satisfies the condition of continuity and differentiability.)

Comment: Look at the proof of Weierstrass theorem. Since f is continuous, reaches a maximum and minimum in the interval. These points have to be in the critical points beacuse f is monotonous elsewhere

Comment: Not rigorous enough. There is a possibility that no critical point exists, such as identity function f(x)=x from [0,1] to [0,1]. And even the domain can be divided into monotone subintervals, you can still obtain infinite local extrema, the existence of the global maximum (minimum) in the set of local extrema is still uncertain. Besides, I'd like to know the reference for the Weierstrass theorem you mentioned, thank you.

Comment: A direct corollary of Weierstrass theorem is exactly the theorem you quoted. The maximum and the minimum given by Weierstrass must be in the extremes (for example, when f is the identity) or in the critical points. The confusion arises because you mixed the concept of 'infinite element set' with that of 'bounded set' which are not the same. If f is differentiable, then im(f') is bounded so the set is bounded and the claim holds true. But it's *useless* to use it in order to find where the extremes are, and that is not the same.

Comment: Simplify to the absurd: 'the set [0,1] has infinite elements, so I can't prove it has a maximum and a minimum'. What do you think?

Comment: Partly agree with you. But what if the set of extrema like this {1/n;n is natural number}? This is what I worry about.

Comment: Just like the example I give in the question, the set of critical points is infinite and discrete, the corresponding set of extrema is infinite and discrete, too. How could I ensure this set of extrema behaves not like the set {1/n;n is natural number} which is infinite but doesn't have a minimum?

Comment: Ok I realized your point. Might we should change the words maximum and minimum for supremum and infimum? If a set is bounded, must have a supremum and infimum. That happens in both examples, what do you think?

Comment: You are right, but my question is unsolved.

Comment: And what do you expect? If the theorem is wrong because the author confused the maximum with the supremum, I don't think that it's possible a generalization. The maximum (minimum) might exist, might not. You have to prove it manually for each particular function which has infinite local extrema.

Comment: That's probably a reasonable compromise, I'll suspend this problem until I truly meet such ill functions. Besides, I'd like to know the reference for the Weierstrass theorem you mentioned earlier, thanks.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)